# I’ll spend whatever of time and energy may be mine. (How does this sentence sound?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I’ll spend whatever of time and energy may be mine.

As a non-native speaker, when I read the sentence above, I thought it's redundant for no reasons.

If you are a native English speaker, what is the sentence like?

Comment: A sentence can't be redundant, though some words in it may be. The sentence is unnatural; it would be more usual to say _whatever time and energy I have/can spare_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native BrE speaker would probably say

> I’ll spend whatever time and energy *[that]I have available* / *I can spare*.

"of" is unnatural and not used in this context.

"may be mine" sounds archaic, it means much the same but isn't used in modern English. It means time that I have for my own use as opposed to that which I spend at work.

Comment: Much the same applies in American English too.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer and comment. I am just taking the opportunity to help readers understand the word "redundant" a little better, because it's not correct here.

Redundant writing means writing that is repeated without adding anything to the meaning. If you call someone an *unmarried bachelor* the word "unmarried" is redundant, because by definition a *bachelor* is unmarried. You've used two words when only one was necessary, and you haven't added anything to the meaning.

Note that the comment is incorrect where it says a sentence can't be redundant. It's true that we often get this wrong by adding unnecessary individual words. But it's certainly possible to write a second sentence that  says the same thing as the first. (It's quite easy to repeat yourself in two sentences one after the other!)