# I will spend whatever of time and energy may be mine

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> I will spend whatever of time and energy may be mine.

Is this sentence possible to rephrase like:

1. I will spend whatever may be mine of time and energy.
2. I will spend whatever time and energy may be mine.
3. I will spend whatever of time and energy that may be mine.
4. I will spend whatever time and energy that may be mine.

?

Comment: The original seems odd.  Is it a quote? Why is there "of" before "time" ?

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331652/i-ll-spend-whatever-of-time-and-energy-may-be-mine-how-does-this-sentence-soun

Comment: Probably you are quoting https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whatever-of-vs-whatever.2510776/ or perhaps this https://www.busan.com/view/busan/view.php?code=20090907000035

Comment: You cannot rephrase a sentence that is wrong from the start, You have [already been told](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/331658/2818) that the sentence you are quoting is wrong, so how can you expect to rephrase it? Did you mean "correct"? Anyway "questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are [off-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) unless a source of concern is clearly specified".

Comment: @None - I would not go so far as to say that it is 'wrong', merely old-fashioned and formal _every Whig must not only know his duty, but must firmly resolve, **whatever of time and labor it may cost**, boldly and faithfully to do it._ US Whig Party campaign circular, January 1840. **also**  _**whatever of time and energy** we give to the keeping of our own vineyard is the very best preparation and aid in keeping the vineyards of others._ **and** _**Whatever of time, talents and treasures** we invest in His service will reap blessing and reward many times over._ (random examples)

Comment: @JamesK - see my comment above.

Comment: gomandeng, all 4 are possible; the one using 'of time' are liable to be perceived either as old-fashioned or even 'wrong', and also 'may be mine' is very old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Whatever of' meaning 'However much' (time, money, etc) is possibly a little old-fashioned, but by no means 'wrong'.

> every Whig must not only know his duty, but must firmly resolve,
> whatever of time and labor it may cost, boldly and faithfully to do
> it.    (US Whig Party campaign circular, January 1840)
>
> Whatever of money found on his person was of course the spoil of war.
> (Letter, USA, 1865)
>
> I take with me whatever of money there is in the house, to defray
> the expenses of my journey.
> (1872 autobiography, Philadelphia, USA)
>
> The king did not now go inland, taking only whatever of money or
> men that lay in his path.
> (1951 translation from Norse)

> also whatever of time and energy we give to the keeping of our own
> vineyard is the very best preparation and aid in keeping the vineyards
> of others.
>
> Whatever of time, talents and treasures we invest in His service will
> reap blessing and reward many times over.
> (undated US Christian material)

Comment: Of course it got its start in England.